# Còmo implementar datapower (PasswordDigest) con envío de token en c#

Tags: c#, .net, soap, seguridad

Sé como implementar para servicios soap desde c#, tengo el llamado de servicio como siempre se hace pero no se que debo cambiar para que funcione implementando la seguridad de datapower con PasswordDigest. muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esto lo probé en una aplicación de consola y funciono, pruébalo con tus datos y luego lo llevas a tu aplicación final y limpias lo que te sobre, espero poder ayudar a alguien y que no pierda el tiempo como me paso a mi

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace SoapServices
{

    class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            PasswordDigestRequest ale = new PasswordDigestRequest();
            ale.CreateHeader();
            Console.WriteLine(ale.CreateHeader());

        }

    }

    public class PasswordDigestRequest
    {
        internal string Username { get; set; }
        internal string Password { get; set; }
        internal string Created { get; set; }

        public PasswordDigestRequest()
        {
            Username = "tuusario";
            Password = "tupassword";
            Created = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
        }

        internal static string CreateHashedPassword(byte[] nonce, string created, string password)
        {
            byte[] createdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(created);
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] combined = new byte[createdBytes.Length + nonce.Length + passwordBytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(nonce, 0, combined, 0, nonce.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(createdBytes, 0, combined, nonce.Length, createdBytes.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(passwordBytes, 0, combined, nonce.Length + createdBytes.Length, passwordBytes.Length);

            System.Net.HttpWebRequest myReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("");
            
               

            return Convert.ToBase64String(SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(combined));
        }

        internal static byte[] GetNonce()
        {
            byte[] nonce = new byte[0x10];
            RandomNumberGenerator generator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            generator.GetBytes(nonce);
            return nonce;
        }

        
        private System.Data.DataSet xmlResponse(string NumeroReferencia)
        {
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            try
            {
                
                 string xml;
                byte[] nonce = GetNonce();
                string nonceStr = Convert.ToBase64String(nonce);
                string hashedPassword = CreateHashedPassword(nonce, Created, Password);

                var soapStr = new StringBuilder();

                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append(Username);
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append(hashedPassword);
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append(nonceStr);
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append(Created);
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                soapStr.Append("");
                string xml;
                
                
                xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:mpi=\"http://osb.bancochile.cl/bch/neg/tarjetaCredito/pagoAvanceTarjetaCredito/pagarTarjetaCreditoRq/mpi\" xmlns:ns=\"http://osb.bancochile.cl/ent/bch/neg/mci/cabeceraServicios/v/4\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://osb.bancochile.cl/ent/bch/infra/mci/cabeceraServicios/v/3\" xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                                      "<soap:Header><wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand=\"true\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
                "<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-42A5B67414DFBD0FF3169523712151218\">" +
                "<wsse:Username>sistema-murex</wsse:Username>"+
                "<wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest\">{password}</wsse:Password>" +
                "<wsse:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">{nonce}</wsse:Nonce>" +
                "<wsu:Created>{created}</wsu:Created>"+
                "</wsse:UsernameToken>"+
            "</wsse:Security>"+
      "<ns:headerRequest>"+
         "<ns:datosConsumidor>"+
            "<ns1:usuario>15125990-1</ns1:usuario>"+
         "</ns:datosConsumidor>"+
         "<ns:datosTransaccion>"+
            "<ns:idTransaccionNegocio>@TRANSACCION@</ns:idTransaccionNegocio>"+
            "<!--Optional: MDW_1908_20230920-1351_161689  -->"+
         "</ns:datosTransaccion>"+
      "</ns:headerRequest>"+
   "</soap:Header>"+
   "<soap:Body>"+
      "<mpi:pagarTarjetaCreditoRq>"+
         "<mpi:fechaHoraCorrienteTransaccion>2023-09-20T10:16:10.000</mpi:fechaHoraCorrienteTransaccion>"+
         "<mpi:horario>PM</mpi:horario>"+
           "<mpi:datosCargo>"+
            "<mpi:cuentaCargo>1621742608</mpi:cuentaCargo>"+
            "<!--Optional:-->"+
            "<mpi:rutClienteCargo>8782091-2</mpi:rutClienteCargo>"+
            "<!--Optional:-->"+
            "<mpi:nombreClienteCargo>Miguel Perez</mpi:nombreClienteCargo>"+
            "<!--Optional:-->"+
            "<mpi:bancaCargo>Personas</mpi:bancaCargo>"+
            "<!--Optional:-->"+
            "<mpi:segmentoCargo>Generico Personas</mpi:segmentoCargo>"+
         "</mpi:datosCargo>"+
         "<!--Optional:-->"+
         "<mpi:listaDataCartola>"+
            "<!--Zero or more 2252590600 2661901 repetitions:-->"+
            "<mpi:datosCartola>"+
               "<!--Optional:-->"+               
               "<!--Optional:-->"+              
            "</mpi:datosCartola>"+
         "</mpi:listaDataCartola>"+
      "</mpi:pagarTarjetaCreditoRq>"+
   "</soap:Body>"+
"</soap:Envelope>";
                
                //esto lo mejoras dentro del xml, yo lo hice asì para probar 
                xml = xml.Replace("{password}", hashedPassword);
                xml = xml.Replace("{nonce}", nonceStr);
                xml = xml.Replace("{created}", Created);
                xml = xml.Replace("@TRANSACCION@", String.Concat("IPPTARJ", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhmmssms")));
                xml = xml.Replace("@EMISOR@", String.Concat("iDEm", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhmmssms")));


                string urlconfig = "tuendpoint";

                string url = urlconfig;

                System.Net.HttpWebRequest myReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(xml);
            string response;
            myReq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            myReq.Method = "POST";
            myReq.Accept = "gzip,deflate";
            myReq.ContentType = @"application / soap + xml; charset = UTF - 8; action = \""pagarTarjetaCredito\""";
            myReq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic c2lGdGVtYS1tdXJlEDTCQG5rMC4wCQ=="; //ESTE CODIGO TE LO DEBE DAR TU PROVEEDOR DE SERVICIOS 
            myReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            myReq.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender1, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);


                using (Stream post = myReq.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    post.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

                System.Net.HttpWebResponse myResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

                Stream responsedata = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responsereader = new StreamReader(responsedata);
                response = responsereader.ReadToEnd();

                ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(response)));
                myResponse.Close();
                responsereader.Close();
                responsedata.Close();
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                ds.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y como lo haces??? esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta... mira por favor [answer]

Comment: Estoy en eso porque lo implemente en soap ui y me funciono pero llevándolo al código me está dando error

Comment: Edite con la respuesta final y lo que me funciono, espero ayude a alguien mas porque no fue fácil lograr que el servicio respondiera